# How to ensure or keep socket alive?

Tags: linux, sockets

Well this is a really open question here "How to ensure or keep socket alive?"

I'm afraid that I have to say "sorry" for this open question. But I still wanna ask some ideas.

How to provide an end-to-end solution for application, which make application know that both ends works with limited resource?

Any solution or suggestion is well appreciated here.

Comment: For tcp sockets, we can set keepalive to true and we can tune the keep alive time intervals for the operating system.

Comment: @Prince John Wesley: Yes, tcp socket has this function. But It can't report error when the connection is lost realtime, consulting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx please find SO_KEEPALIVE section.

Comment: The reason you don't know when the connection is lost is because your computer is not told. Any intermediate router may stop forwarding your packets at any time, with or without notification. `SO_KEEPALIVE` mainly helps with routers that have a stateful firewall (which would be a reason for the router to stop forwarding). With keepalives, your app is usually told when the keepalives are not replied to within the timeout, which is the best one can hope to achieve.

Comment: @Simon Richter: I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a TCP socket.

You can't guarantee that it's alive at any given time. If enabling SO_KEEPALIVE does not do what you want, you'll need to do custom keepalive packets within the application protocol.

Some protocols, for isntance, have a "NOOP" command which can be used.

Under Linux (but not necessarily other OSs) you can modify the keepalive interval used by SO_KEEPALIVE on a per-socket basis (see man 7 tcp)

Comment: Excellent, you mentioned about "NOOP". Well, it's something like heart beat checking mechanism. Yes, it's on application side. Maybe we have to implement kind of this mechanism in session layer. But you know, time for hear beat consumes resources, which depends on time interval for checking.